# How to regenerate firebase cache

Tags: firebase, caching, next.js, google-cloud-functions

I have some trouble with my nextjs project (nextjs website) hosted on google-firebase. I use google-cloud-functions to run this website.

I would like to use cache. As I understand web-apps which hosted on firebase are automatically store results to CDN when there are right headers.
I add cache headers to my pages.

```js
# pages/[[...slug]].tsx
export const getServerSideProps = context => {
    ...
    const cacheControlHeader = `public, max-age=${secondsForImages}`;
    const expiresHeader = new Date(Date.now() + secondsForImages * 1000).toUTCString();
    context.res.setHeader('Cache-Control', cacheControlHeader);
    context.res.setHeader('Expires', expiresHeader);
    return { props };
    ...
}
```

For example: `Expires: Sun, 24 Dec 2023 19:01:34 GMT` (*+1 day from Sun, 23 Dec 2023 19:01:34 GMT*)

Firebase stores pages well. After first slow request, I get this page quickly from cache

Than, I would like to change some page and than clear and regenerate a cache of it. I use `curl -X PURGE https://www.mywebsite.ololo/mypage` and it also works well

For regenerating I try to do something like this `curl -v https://www.mywebsite.ololo/mypage` (I tried wget also). I get correct headers everything well... But this works only for next curl requests and doesn't works for browser. When I'm trying to get it from my browser as usually it doing slow (first time).

Could anybody help me how to make request from bash (or node-app or php-app) to regenerate cache for browser?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're describing here.  Are you talking about a website that you built and hosted with Firebase Hosting?  Is the cache you're talking about actually the Firebase Hosting CDN page cache?  Also, you tagged this with Firestore, but it's not clear how Firestore is involved here.  And I'm not clear how to reproduce this issue - you have no code or anything that describes how things are set up.  Please edit the question to provide a complete minimal example of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @DougStevenson I added some details. Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

This header:

```
public, max-age=${secondsForImages}
```

This tells both the target browser and any intermediary servers that the response you send is valid for `max-age` seconds. There is no generic way to purge the file before that.

If the response may expire sooner, either send a shorter max-age; or consider generating a unique URL for each unique response (e.g. by including a hash in there).

---

**Update**: there is an undocumented way to purge the contents for a specific URL which a team member described [here](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/_q9qM82QV6U/m/Xsy1OP6BFQAJ). As said in that answer, there's no guarantee this will still/continue to work, but it's worth a shot:

```
curl -X PURGE https://my.firebasehosting.site.com/path/to/content
```

Comment: Ok. let's forget about headers. I want to regenerate cache after deploying my application. And I want to do it by some console script. For example `firebase deploy && curl -X GET https://mywebsite.ololo/mypage`

Comment: There is no API to actively clear the cache in Firebase Hosting or in the user's browser. Files are removed when they are expired (according to their max-age) or when they haven't been recently used and space is needed.

Comment: my problem is not how to remove user's cache but how to regenerate cache in google CDN

Comment: Same answer though: there is no official API to actively clear the cache in Firebase Hosting. Although there is an **undocumented** way to purge a specific URL, shown here: https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/_q9qM82QV6U/m/Xsy1OP6BFQAJ